# When I test my POST route for Django Rest Framework API it returns a 401 not authenticated even though logged in

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I attempt to test my Create/POST route for my Django Rest Framework API I receive a response status code of 401 with the error detail telling me `ErrorDetail(string=u'Authentication credentials were not provided.', code=u'not_authenticated')`. The weird thing is I Django tells me I'm authenticated when I check is is_authenticated.

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this? All relevant code provided below.

```
# test_api.py

def authorise_user_and_test_is_authenticated(self, user_id):
    """
    Log in user and test this is successful
    """
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    self.client.login(username=user.username, password=user.password)
    authorised_user = auth.get_user(self.client)
    return self.assertTrue(user.is_authenticated())

def test_create_project(self):
    '''
        When given valid parameters a project is created.
    '''
    user = User.objects.get(username="user_001")
    self.authorise_user_and_test_is_authenticated(user.id) # pass of authenication and auth testing to method, when tested with is_authenicated() it returns true.

    response = self.client.post('/api/user/{0}/project/create/'.format(user.id),
                                 json.dumps({"model_name": "POSTed Project",
                                             "description": "Project tested by posting",
                                             "shared_users[]": [2]
                                             }),
                                 content_type='application/json')

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

---

```
# views.py

class MyCreateView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    pass
    serializer_class = FerronPageCreateAndUpdateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('user'))

    def post(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        # This dictionary is used to ensure that the last_modified_by field is always updated on post to be the current user
        print request.data
        request_data = {
            'user': request.user.id,
            'model_name': request.data['model_name'],
            'description': request.data['description'],
            'last_modified_by': request.user.id,
            'shared_users': request.data.getlist('shared_users[]', [])
        }
        serializer = FerronPageCreateAndUpdateSerializer(data=request_data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

---

```
# settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
       'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
   ),
}
```

---

```
# url matcher

url(r'^user/(?P<user>\d+)/project/create/$', MyCreateView.as_view(), name='create-project')
```

---

```
class FerronPageCreateAndUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
shared_users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=User.objects.all(), read_only=False)
description  = serializers.CharField(max_length=300, trim_whitespace=True, required=False, allow_blank=True)

class Meta:
    model = Project
    fields = [
      'pk',
      'user',
      'data',
      'model_name',
      'description',
      'created_at',
      'date_modified',
      'shared_users',
      'last_modified_by'
```

### ]

Comment: does the view working with normal API requests?

Comment: rest does not have state .... you should auth another way (ie tokens attached to req) ... but basically that client was not authenticated...

Comment: Hi Todd! Are you only having problems in the test? Either way the first step would be to remove `pass` from the first line after the `MyCreateView` class declaration. Next is to share the `self.authorise_user_and_test_is_authenticated` method or the whole test class if you can. Authentication in tests can be a pain so I've found using `self.client.force_authenticate(user=user)` in DRF tests to be an easy work around.

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback so quickly. @JPG this works with normal api requests. @joran I had tried to access auth_token via `user.auth_token` but the key wasn't recognised? I'm not 100% sure on how to set that up.

Comment: @JacobHarding Yes it only gives me problems during the test. However, when I've testing been doing get requests via the API that works fine. Have edited my question to include the`self.authorise_user_and_test_is_authenticated` method now. I tried `force_authenticate` but seem my post seems to still return a 401.

Comment: This feels like a permissions issue because your permissions are `DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly` which would allow GET requests but fail on a request to create. What does the `authorised_user` variable contain and what is the result of `authorised_user.is_authenticated()`? You will also need to create and set the auth token for each user. Take a look at [the docs](https://django-rest-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) on how to do that.

Comment: @JacobHarding I've removed `DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly` and replaced it with `'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'` however it still returned `401 - Authentication credentials were not provided`. When I checked, `authorised_user` is `<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x111626b10>`. When I checked  `authorised_user.__dict__` is was equal to `{}`.

Comment: `AnonymousUser` means the user isn't authenticated and the reason you are getting the 401. Try changing your permissions to `rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny` as a test just to see it work. Were you able to create an auth token for your user?

Answer (score 0):

Turn's out the issue was here `self.client.login(username=user.username, password=user.password)` inside the `authorise_user_and_test_is_authenticated(self, user_id)` method.

The problem was that I was using the password an instance of a user I had already created. This meant when I gave the argument `password=user.password`, I was trying to log in using a password that had already been hashed. What I needed to do instead was log in with the original unhashed version of the password e.g. `password='openseasame'`.